# How to use two service call in one component using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the same component, I written the code to call one API request and got the response, using that response I suppose to call other API. So, Is that possible to call the other API in the same component.

```
var React  = require('react');
    var routerModule = require('react-router');
    var Link = routerModule.Link;

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    var ProductDetails = React.createClass({
      getInitialState:function(){
        return {
          productDetail:{
            productlisting: {
              PTY_NAME:{},             
            },
            partyid:{}
          }

        }
      }, 
      componentWillMount:function(){
        $.ajax({
          url:'http://example.com'+this.props.params.itemId,
          dataType:'json',
          cache:false,
          success:function(data){
            this.setState({
              productDetail:data
            });
          }.bind(this)
        });

      },   
      render: function() {
        var productDetail = this.state.productDetail;
        return (
          <div> 

            <div className="scrollContent">
              <div className="cards">
                {productBanner}
                <div className="cardBoxContent">
                  <div className="circleIcon whiteBg user-icon">{profileImage}</div>
                  <h2>{pdItems.PRD_NAME}</h2>  
                </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });

    module.exports = ProductDetails;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean sending another AJAX request inside the first one's callback?

Comment: Just create two functions, one for each request. Then call the function where you want to. You can add as many custom functions to the component as you like, such as `myRequest` and `myRequest2`

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Please give any sample code

Answer (score 0):

You can sequence the service calls in any fashion you want, but using Promise will be easier and is a good thing to do here (less deeply nested callbacks). You can rewrite the API calls like this -

```
componentWillMount(){
    Promise.resolve($.ajax(...))
           .then(function(firstCallResult){
                     // Do something with firstCallResult
                     ...
                     $.ajax(...);
            });
}
```

**UPDATE**
Modified example to demonstrate how the first service call value is sent to the function inside `then`.

Comment: how to get data from first ajax call to second ajax call

Comment: The next function invoked in the `then` call receives results from the first invocation. Updated my example above.